# Ignore tags in `org-end-of-line` and similar motions

Tags: org-mode, evil, motion

Is there a convenient function for jumping to the last *non-tag* character in the line of an org-mode heading? For instance...

```
* This is |my header     :tag1:tag2:
```

I would like a command that moves the point (`|`) to:

```
* This is my header|     :tag1:tag2
```

Ideally, I would love something that implements a full set of evil motions for this, so that commands like `dg_` will not delete tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org-end-of-line`, bound by default to `C-e` in org-mode buffers, is probably what you are looking for. The doc string for the function says:

> org-end-of-line is an interactive Lisp closure in
>   ‘../org-mode/lisp/org.el’.
>
> It is bound to `C-e`, `<end>`.
>
> (org-end-of-line &optional N)
>
> Go to the end of the line, but before ellipsis, if any.
>
> **If this is a headline, and ‘org-special-ctrl-a/e’ is not nil or
>   symbol ‘reversed’, ignore tags on the first attempt, and only
>   move to after the tags when the cursor is already beyond the end
>   of the headline.**
>
> If ‘org-special-ctrl-a/e’ is symbol ‘reversed’ then ignore tags
>   on the second attempt.
>
> With argument N not nil or 1, move forward N - 1 lines first.

So, in summary, the trick is to `(setq org-special-ctrl-a/e t)` (or similar) and then use `org-end-of-line`. Note that this will propagate through to `evil-org-end-of-line` as well, so all the standard Evil motions will work.

Comment: Aha! Thank you! I was already aware of `org-end-of-line` (via `evil-org-end-of-line`, which uses it by default for all its motion), but was unaware of the `org-special-ctrl-a/e` setting, which did what I needed. I revised your answer slightly to highlight that.